# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: showcreate1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i read before write this questions other questions but nothing work, i check javascript is loaded, i try to use jquery where i used $ but nothing..

My problem is ajax isn't working, the error is the title question.

I have some views, menu.blade.php code:

```
@extends('cms.public.layouts.default')
@section('content')

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
  <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="ajaxwindow">

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
      listProject();
      $("#buttoncreate").click(function(e){
        $("#buttoncreate").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        listUploadProject();
      });
    });

      var listProject = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"{{ url('admin/project/listall') }}",
          success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      var listUploadProject = function()
     {
       $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:"{{ url('admin/project/create') }}",
         success: function(data){
           $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
         }
       });
     }
</script>
@stop
```

In this view i use ajax and is working, it shows this view (listall.blade.php):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead style="color:white">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Slug</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Public</th>
        <th>Path header</th>
        <th>Path home</th>
        <th>Fecha creación</th>
        <th>Fecha ultima actualización</th>
        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="color:white">
     @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
      <tr>
        <th>{{$project->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->pathheader}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->pathhome}}</td>
        <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->created_at))}}</td>
        <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->updated_at))}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
    @endforeach
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br><br>
```

And if i click on button create he goes to this view (createproject.blade.php):

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="createproject">

</div>
<br><br><br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        showcreate1();
    });

      var showcreate1 = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"{{ url('admin/project/createform1') }}",
          success: function(data){
            $('#createproject').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
</script>
```

The url '/admin/project/createform1' is called by the controller:

```
 public function CreateProjectForm1()
   {
       return view('cms.public.views.projects.createprojectform1');
   } 




 <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <h3>1/2</h3>
        </div>
        <hr>


        <div class="col-md-12" id="formcreateproject">

            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label name="title">Slug:</label>
                <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <label name="order">Order:</label>
                <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <label name="public">Public:</label>
                <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                 <label name="body">Header</label>
                <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
                <label name="body">Home</label>
                <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                <br><br><br>

              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
```

Why the last view isn't loaded?

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

```
showcreate1 = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"{{ url('admin/project/createform1') }}",
          success: function(data){
            $('#createproject').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
```

without var. declaring it with var will limit it's scope. removing var will make it a global function which can be accessed any where in the page, or do this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var showcreate1 = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"{{ url('admin/project/createform1') }}",
          success: function(data){
            $('#createproject').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
        showcreate1();
    });
```

Comment: Without bar error change, retorn now is showcreate1 is not declared

Comment: The second option was successful, maybe render the view and the function isn't loaded? Or why, if you declare the function first it works?

Comment: 'var' in your declaration actually makes it as a local variable which is inaccessible to your usage which is inside a function that will be executed when the page is ready.

Please mark the answer if it is correct :D

Answer (score 0):

showcreate1 is not a function because you're calling it before it's defined.
Change  `var showcreate1 = function() {}` to `function showcreate1() {}` Or just move the document ready code below the function definition.

Comment: in javascript you can use a function before you declare it in your code

Comment: Yes, using function declaration, not function expression.

Comment: true. function expressions aren't hoisted so they can't be used until they appear in the code